# Javascript/Jquery regex for matched key and return its Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

```
var t = {
"Word1, Word2 Word3":"Word1, Word2", 
"Word5, Word6":"Word6", "Word7":"Word7", 
"Word8, Word9 and Word10":"Word8 and Word10"
}

//has value after page load, its saved from a cookie
var z = "Word9 and Word10"
```

Requirement: I would like to pass the variable `z` and retrieve the matched value from the object `t`.

So in this case it should return "Word8 and Word10" so i could use that value to make API call etc. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Loop through the elements of the object. Test if `z` is in the key. If it is, return the value.

Comment: What's your question? Asking for suggestions isn't a specific question.

Comment: Have a look at [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). Either of them should help you solve the problem.

Comment: What if you have `"Word99999, Word9 and Word10"`? This seems like a not well thought strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you want to handle duplicates wasn't mentioned, this solution  loops through all the object's keys and checks if the key value includes the `z` variable

```js
const t = {
"Word1 Word2 Word3":"Word1 Word2", 
"Word5 Word6":"Word6", "Word7":"Word7", 
"Word8 Word9 and Word10":"Word8 and Word10"
}
const z = "Word9 and Word10"

for (const key of Object.keys(t)) {
    if (key.includes(z)) {
        console.log(t[key])
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason for not using the exact OP's input?

Comment: What do you mean @RokoC.Buljan, I did use exact OP's input?